# Замена входящих данных с сохранением нужных

Tags: php

Возникла такая проблема, что при обработке текста мне нужно заменить везде где присутствует некий код, например:

```
Текст[img|http://img.img/]Текст2[img|http://img2.img2]
```

нужно заменить везде на `<img src="http://img.img" />` и со вторым аналогично. У меня есть код, который вполне работает, но работает он правильно только тогда, когда принимает только одну строку `[img]`, а другая не обрабатывается. Вот код:

```
$patternImg = '/\[(img)\|(.*)\]/i';
$replacementImg = '<img src="$2" />';
$text = preg_replace($patternImg, $replacementImg, $text);
```

Как правильно решить эту задачу уже не знаю :(
 Буду признателен за объяснения и помощь в решении данной проблемы.

Comment: Попробуйте в двойных кавычках "<img src=\"$2\" />"

Comment: @DmitryKozlov не помогло :(

Answer (score 0):

В круглые скобки вашего шаблона нужно добавить квантификатор `?`:

```
$text = 'Текст[img|http://img.img/]Текст2[img|http://img2.img2]';

$patternImg = '~\[img\|(.*?)\]~i';
$replacementImg = '<img src="$1" />';
$text = preg_replace($patternImg, $replacementImg, $text);

var_dump($text);
```

Результат:

```
Текст<img src="http://img.img/" />Текст2<img src="http://img2.img2" />
```